# Help with structure for "single-page" Ajax website

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax

I know about the rules and this is not really a question that can be answered, but I really need help with this.

I'm making a website that have a javascript music player that cannot be interrupted every time the user changes between pages. So, the site must be a sort of single page, loading the ASPX files with AJAX.

What structure should I use for this?

If I use a Masterpage with the player and separated aspx files, will I be able to load these files with ajax?

Any help with structure or an ajax sample would be appreciated.

Comment: Will these pages have any functionality on them? Or just static text pages? If so, you could store the pages in a database and then load the content into the main page?

Comment: Could you have a page with 2 iframes and do all the navigation in 1, leaving the other to run the music?

Comment: Yeah.. the pages have some functionality, and I'd rather not use iframes if possible

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you leverage the [MVC Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc) for this.  You can then easily call Controller's Action methods via client-side AJAX calls.  Here's a simplified example:

```
// jQuery AJAX call.
function getContacts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/Contacts/GetContacts',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var contacts = response;
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('oops!');
        }
    });
}


// Server-side.
public class ContactsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetContacts()
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        List<Contacts> contacts = DataAccess.GetContacts();
        result.Data = contacts;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: And if MVC is just not an option for you, then look into calling PageMethods/WebMethods via AJAX - http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article454-using-pagemethods-and-json-in-aspnet-ajax-.aspx