# How to use ajax with asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there any way to use ajax I'm using Jquery for this) with asp.net webforms without having to run through the pages life cycle?

Comment: why would you want to do this ?

Comment: Because going through the Page life cycle is pointless when all you need is some data retrieved or an action performed through AJAX.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, as you mentioned, you can [use jQuery to call Page Methods directly](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/), without incurring the overhead of MicrosoftAjax.js and the service proxy it generates to enable the `PageMethods.MethodName()` syntax.

Given a static `[WebMethod]` decorated method in `PageName.aspx` that's called `MethodName`, this is an example of how you could call it on the client-side:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting with msg.d here.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could use Web Methods or Http Handlers.  Web Methods might be a bit easier, and are just server side static functions which are decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute.

Here's an example:

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SayHello(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    #(function()
    {
        $(".hellobutton").click(function()
        {
            PageMethods.SayHello("Name", function(result)
            {
                alert(result);
            });
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" class="hellobutton" value="Say Hello" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Page Methods, as they are called.

They are essentially methods on a `Page`, but are declared as static.

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   [WebMethod]
   public static string Reverse(string message) {
      return message.Reverse();
   }
}
```

They can then be used like this from client scripting:

```
function reverseMyString(message) {
   // Magically generated code appears
   PageMethods.SendForm(message, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
}

function OnSucceeded(result) { alert(result) }
function OnFailed(error) { alert(error.get_message()) }
```

They are pretty neat compared to asmx web services since they can stay within the same Web Forms functionality that a particular page builds up.

Answer (score 1):

There sure is a way.  Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262861/help-with-structure-for-single-page-ajax-website/5265562#5265562).  That particular example uses MVC on the back-end, but you can similarly do it with basic ASP.NET - Just look into calling [PageMethods/WebMethods via AJAX](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article454-using-pagemethods-and-json-in-aspnet-ajax-.aspx).

One of the keys is to declare a static method with the WebMethod attribute on it.

Comment: You may also consider UpdatePanels, but the drawback there is that while it looks to the end-user like only a portion of the page is refreshing, you're still posting back the whole ViewState and going through the full page life cycle on the server.  Yuck.

Comment: The links provided should explain everything you need.