# How to call codebehind function without postback with ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a controller:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="MyFunction" runat="server" />
```

I want to be able to call MyFunction without the page reloading.  Is this possible with ajax or something?  If so how would I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ajax with asp.net webforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331986/how-to-use-ajax-with-asp-net-webforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Make Client-Side Network Callbacks with Asp.net Ajax using this function you can call your code behind methods without reloading your page. To use this methods you should write your methods as static type.

You can refer this video

http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-make-client-side-network-callbacks-with-aspnet-ajax

You have one more option using the jQuery Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the ASP.Net instructional videos.  Should cover most, if not all, of your questions.

[AJAX Videos: The Official Microsoft ASP.NET Site](http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use **page methods**.

Add a static method to your page, decorated with the [`WebMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(string someParam) 
{
}
```

Enable page methods in your [`ScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods.aspx):

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="True" ... />
```

And then you can call it from the client side, using JavaScript (that you can wire to the OnClientClick event of your button):

```
PageMethods.MyMethod("some value", successCallback, errorCallback);
```

For more details read the "Calling Static Methods in an ASP.NET Web Page" section on this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to download [Ajax Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=883) and install it.

After you do this place instead `<asp:Button OnClick="MyFunction" runat="server" />` the following

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Your Text" OnClick="MyFunction" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

MyFunction would be a c#/vb function written in your page behind code, not a javascript function. I specified this because i've seen many mistakes that people make regarding this one. OnClick attribute is for c#/vb function and OnClientClick is for javascript function.

For more information regarding how to add ajax functionality to an ASP .NET Page go [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet-35/videos/adding-ajax-functionality-to-an-existing-aspnet-page)

Comment: but the drawback there is that while it looks to the end-user like only a portion of the page is refreshing, you're still posting back the whole ViewState and going through the full page life cycle on the server. Yuck.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to warp your code with an UpdatePanel

There are many examples if you [google it](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=updatePanel+examples+asp.net).

Comment: but the drawback there is that while it looks to the end-user like only a portion of the page is refreshing, you're still posting back the whole ViewState and going through the full page life cycle on the server. Yuck.

Comment: @Fernando68 For most of cases is not that bad - now if you have some kind of high loaded and heavy used page, you can make your javascript code and make a better ajax call - but the update panel is very nice, where you can find such a good automation so easy ?

Comment: True, but the problem I am having is that the UpdatePanel, as it is, wipes all my CSS settings due to the full page recycle. I already have jscript code highlighting rows, etc, but as soon as I click a checkbox to go into the server-side code, even with UpdatePanel around it, I loose all my CSS. I think using webmethods is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowModal" Text="Show" 
     OnClick="btnShowModal_Click" /> 
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="HiddenForModal" style="display: none" />
<ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="Modal1" runat="server" 
     TargetControlID="HiddenForModal" PopupControlID="PopupPanel" />......it may help u
```

Comment: No. That only uses Ajax to send a popup request. Postback will still occurr, and even if you use UpdatePanel the drawback there is that while it looks to the end-user like only a portion of the page is refreshing, you're still posting back the whole ViewState and going through the full page life cycle on the server. Yuck.