# ASP.NET Drop Down List Selection Refreshing Entire Page despite AsyncPostBackTrigger

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have an UpdatePanel with a group of DropDownLists. When I select a Department from the drop down list, it causes the Area and Tracking Groups to be updated with new values.

The problem with this is it also causes the entire page to refresh, which causes some of my textboxes that dynamically appear to disappear.

I have tried using AsyncPostBackTriggers to no avail. It still causes the rest of the page to be refreshed.

HTML code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlMCSearch" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
    <ContentTemplate>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="SEARCH_TABLE">
            ...
            <div class="SEARCH_ROW">
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL25">
                    <b>Department</b>
                </div>
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL75">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMCSearch_Department" runat="server" CssClass="select" Width="210px"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="Department_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="SEARCH_ROW">
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL25">
                    <b>Area</b>
                </div>
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL75">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMCSearch_Area" runat="server" CssClass="select" Width="210px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
            <div class="SEARCH_ROW">
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL25">
                    <b>Tracking Group</b>
                </div>
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL75">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMCSearch_TrackingGroup" runat="server" CssClass="select" Width="210px" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="SEARCH_ROW">
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL25">
                    <b>Date operator</b>
                </div>
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL75">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdBtnMCSearch_DateOperators" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        RepeatLayout="Flow" class="dateOperator">
                        <asp:ListItem ID="rdBtnMCSearch_DateOperators_LessThan" Text="Less than or equal to" Value="ltoet"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem ID="rdBtnMCSearch_DateOperators_GreaterThan" Text="Greater than or equal to" Selected="True" Value="gtoet"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem ID="rdBtnMCSearch_DateOperators_Between" Text="Between" Value="between"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="SEARCH_ROW">
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL25">
                    <b>Start Date(s)</b>
                </div>
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL75">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMCSearch_StartDate1" runat="server" Width="195px" class="startDate1">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMCSearch_StartDate2" runat="server" Width="195px" class="startDate2">
                    </asp:TextBox>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="SEARCH_ROW">
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL25">
                    <b>End Date(s)</b>
                </div>
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL75">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMCSearch_EndDate1" runat="server" Width="195px" class="endDate1">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMCSearch_EndDate2" runat="server" Width="195px" class="endDate2">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="SEARCH_ROW">
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL50">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMCSearch_Search" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="submit" OnClick="SearchForMCItems"/>
                </div>
                <div class="SEARCH_CELL CELL50 FLOAT_RIGHT">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMCSearch_Clear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="ClearMCSearchFields"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMCSearch_Department" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMCSearch_Area" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMCSearch_TrackingGroup" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnMCSearch_Search" />
    </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Before selecting a department:

[image: Before selecting a department]

After selecting a department:

[image]

I have looked at most of the Stack Overflow posts about AsyncPostBackTriggers and DropDownLists.

I have checked and tried:

1. Not using any ClientIDMode="Static" for my controls
2. Tried adding ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
3. Tried using nested panels

Comment: From what I can gather from your post: `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMCSearch_Department" runat="server" CssClass="select" Width="210px"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="Department_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>` This drop down is set to `AutoPostBack=true` and from your post it looks like you are experiencing this issue when changing the value of the `Department` drop down. Don't do an `AutoPostBack` on the drop down?

Comment: I have to do AutoPostBack=true because the selected Department informs the Areas and Tracking Groups. So we have to go to the server to get that info.

Comment: Use `ajax` to get that data from the server `async` Then populate `Area` and  `Tracking Groups`

Comment: That is the only thing I haven't tried at this point. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Try setting `AutoPostBack = "false"` as a test to see if your dynamic inputs stay in place when changing the `Department` drop down. If that keeps everything in view, add the `ajax` call I suggested and you should be good to go. Just in case you need an example of using `ajax` in your project: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331986/how-to-use-ajax-with-asp-net-webforms)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Started to get it to work.

Comment: Of note, the controls you are mentioning disappearing, appear to be inside the update panel. You'd have to repeat the logic that put them there, or not have them inside the panel. I may be reading your example wrong though.