# Problem while using AJAX requesting webmethod info from VB file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I've been trying to call a VB.NET function from JavaScript for the website I've been working on, and found out about AJAX and started trying to use it.

(For reference, my target framework is 4.6.1.)

The following is a snippet of my VB.NET code, where `PopulateDetailSection()` is something which returns a string which is supposed to be the text from the div, but my breakpoint never hits this function.

```
System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True, BufferResponse:=False)
    Protected Shared Function PopulateDetail() As HtmlGenericControl

        Return PopulateDetailSection()
    End Function
```

and as for the AJAX call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "frmActiveTrackingG.aspx/PopulateDetail",
                type: "GET",
                //contentType: "application/json: charset=utf-8",
                dataType:"html",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

I've tried alerting several things, but it keeps returning undefined unless I alert data which appears to return the aspx file starting with the header.

I usually don't ask questions here, but I'm truly stumped on this.

Comment: The code should be in an .asmx.vb file - create one by adding a new item to the project with a type of "Web Service". That will stop it from doing all the scaffolding, such as the header, that goes along with an .aspx item.

Answer (score 1):

There some issues with your JavaScript. As described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5332290/428010 you need to post on the web page/method.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "frmActiveTrackingG.aspx/PopulateDetail",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json: charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

On the VB side the method need to be *public* not *protected*.